# ERROR: Laser has to be mounted planar

Tags: slam, navigation, coordinate, gmapping, slam-gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS indigo.

I published the TF using static_transform_publisher from tf package.

Using the following tag to publish the transformation between the base_link and the camera_link:

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link2_broadcaster" args="0 0 1 0 0 0 1 base_link camera_link 100" />
```

When I started slam_gmapping node it gives the following error:

```
Laser has to be mounted planar! Z-coordinate has to be 1 or -1, but gave: 0.00000
```

The problem is solved when I changed the Y coordinate to 1 or -1 . But this is not the right transformation of my robot.

UPDATE:

This is my
[transformation tree](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cuw61yj1r7s0zx5/frames.pdf?dl=0)

and this is the launch file I used:

```
 <launch>
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_camera_broadcaster" args="0 0 1 0 0 0 1 base_link camera_link 100" />    
    <include file="$(find pointcloud_to_laserscan)/launch/pointcloud_to_laserscan.launch"/>
    <node pkg="roboteq_motor" type="odom" name="odom"/>
  <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" output="screen">
    <rosparam>
      odom_frame: odom
      map_update_interval: 1.0
      maxUrange: 30.0
      maxRange: 60.0
      sigma: 0.05
      kernelSize: 1
      lstep: 0.05
      astep: 0.05
      iterations: 5
      lsigma: 0.075
      ogain: 3.0
      lskip: 0
      linearUpdate: 0.5
      angularUpdate: 0.436
      temporalUpdate: -1.0
      resampleThreshold: 0.5
      particles: 80
      xmin: -1.0
      ymin: -1.0
      xmax: 1.0
      ymax: 1.0
      delta: 0.025
      llsamplerange: 0.01
      llsamplestep: 0.01
      lasamplerange: 0.005
      lasamplestep: 0.005
      base_frame: base_link
    </rosparam>
</node>
</launch>
```

Note: I didn't publish The odom to base_link transformation using static_transform_publisher because the node odom publishes this information using sendTransform. Is that ok? or they are different things?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206258/error:-laser-has-to-be-mounted-planar/) by [saraalsiari](https://answers.ros.org/users/22024/saraalsiari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-03-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [slivingston](https://answers.ros.org/users/829/slivingston/) on 2015-03-30**:
Have you also tried `args="0 0 1 0 0 0 base_link camera_link 100"`? (Alternative format for static_transform_publisher.)

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2015-03-31**:
It doesn't look like gmapping is plotting your map in the base_link frame and therefore there is probably another transformation in the chain - take care to see that the sensor frame and the map frame (and not sensor frame and base link frame) are planar wrt to each other.

**Comment by [saraalsiari](https://answers.ros.org/users/22024/saraalsiari/) on 2015-04-02**:
@slivingston Thank you but didn't work

**Comment by [saraalsiari](https://answers.ros.org/users/22024/saraalsiari/) on 2015-04-02**:
@2ROS0 How can I make sure that the sensor frame and the map frame are planar? It might me a basic thing but I'm a beginner. Also, I updated the question with an image of my transformation tree, please take a look at it.

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2015-04-02**:
Can you update the launch file you're using to start the gmapping node? @saraalsiari

**Comment by [saraalsiari](https://answers.ros.org/users/22024/saraalsiari/) on 2015-04-03**:
@2ROS0 Yes I updated it and the same problem occurs. Please see the new update in the question.

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2016-01-30**:
@saraalsiari, I got the same problem, did you solve it by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This answer in VREP forum might help you : http://www.forum.coppeliarobotics.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=2847

---

Originally posted by [skywalker](https://answers.ros.org/users/21755/skywalker/) with karma: 16 on 2015-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0